# Not able to retrieve key value

Tags: javascript

I have data in format

```
var data = "{key1=value1,key2=value2}"
```

I want to perform something like when I have key1 i should get value1 in return.
For example:

```
var val = data[key1];
//val value should be value1
```

Comment: Try formatting your data in a more "standard" format, like JSON. Or just use an object literal `var data = {key1:'value1',key2:'value2'};`

Comment: You are using a wrong syntax. the correct one is var data = {key1 : value1, key2 : value2}, then access like data.key1 returns value1

Comment: If you're saying that you're getting some data in that format, then you're going to have to write a simple parser to extract it.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? If you expect us to write a parser for your custom data format, that's not gonna happen. If you are truly wondering why you can't access your data, then you should go back and read a good JavaScript tutorial. Either way I don't think his question is going to be of use to anyone else.

Comment: @ Felix Kling  
Thank you very much for overwhelming response . I really appreciate it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here. The first is that your 'data' variable in its current form is just a string. You would need to remove the enclosing quotes, and replace your ' = ' with ' : ' which will make it a JavaScript object so you can index into it.

The second issue is that 'value1' in your object is not defined. You would either need to create another variable called 'value1' and initialize it, then stick it into your data object, but their are better ways to go about it if this is what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are just creating key/value pairs, then you could do something like:

```
var data = {key1:'value1',key2:'value2'};
```

You could then access the 'key1' value by doing the following:

```
var val = data['key1'];
```

or

```
var val = data.key1;
```

Here is a fiddle to illustrate how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/LxjN4/

Comment: Are you getting the data from another source? Or is it hard coded into the app? If you are working with JSON data you would need to use JSON.parse(yourJsonData) as mentioned by Infer-On to create a JavaScript object you can work with.

Comment: You are using incorrect syntax for your  "object literal".

Comment: Ahh... thank you. That would have definitely been an issue. It has since been corrected.